# Visualizar valores ManyToMany en DJango

Tags: django

Veran, en mi proyecto necesito utilizar variables manytomany para almacenar claves foraneas que apuntan a varios valores.

Codigo en models.py:

```
class desplazamiento(models.Model):
    nombre=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    descripcion=RichTextField(max_length=150)
    foto=models.ImageField(null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class animal(models.Model):
    ncomun=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ncientifico=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    foto=models.ImageField()
    categoria=models.ForeignKey(categoria,null=True)
    alimentacion=models.ForeignKey(alimentacion,null=True)
    desplazamiento=models.ManyToManyField(desplazamiento, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.ncomun
```

Codigo en views.py:

```
def datos_animal(request,i):
    try:
        ani=animal.objects.get(pk=i)  
    except animal.DoesNotExist:
        ani=None
    return render(request,"indice.html",{"ani":ani})
```

Codigo HTML:

```
<body>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Más detalles acerca del animal</h1>
<img style="width: 250px; height: 200px; position:relative; left: 40%;" src="{% static ani.foto %}" />
    <ul>
        <li>Nombre comun: {{ani.ncomun}}</li>
        <li>Nombre cientifico: {{ani.ncientifico}}</li>
        <li>Categoria: {{ani.categoria.nombre}}</li>
        <li>Alimentación: {{ani.alimentacion.nombre}}</li>
    </ul>

            <h2>Metodos de desplazamiento:</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for u in ani.deplazamiento.all %}
        <li>{{u}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
<button style="position: absolute; left: 44%; bottom: 10%;" onclick="viaje('javascript:history.back(-1)')">Retroceder</button>

</body>
```

Sin embargo, aunque al comprobar en admin el animal tiene su categoria, no se muestra en esta vista.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Que puedo estar haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que es seguro es que hay un error de sintaxis

```
{% for u in ani.deplazamiento.all %}
```

debería ser:

```
{% for u in ani.desplazamiento.all %}
```

Comment: ¡Gracias, ya lo he arreglado!